# How to load the contacts photos and show in the list of contacts?

Tags: android, list, photo, android-contacts

I am showing a list of some contacts. I want to show the photos of the contacts too. These I want to load directly from the contacts and show them in the list. So should I do this in an adapter? Also how can I do this?

I have added only selected contacts in the list. So I have to show photos of only selected contacts.

I tried like this:

```
 public class InviteeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InviteeAdapter.MyViewHolder>{


    private List<Invitee> inviteeList;
    int status;
    Context context;
    Cursor mCursor;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public ImageView profileImage;
        private String imageUri;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleName);
            profileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventsIcon);
        }
    }


    public InviteeAdapter(List<Invitee> inviteeList,Context context) {
        this.inviteeList = inviteeList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.invitee_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Invitee invitee = inviteeList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(invitee.getFName()+" "+invitee.getLName());
       // String imageUri = invitee.getImageUri();



        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };

        mCursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "upper("+ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");

        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

            holder.imageUri = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

           // photo.setImageUri(image_uri);
        }

        if(holder.imageUri!=null) {

            holder.profileImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(holder.imageUri));
        }

       /* status = invitee.;

        if(status == 0)
        {
            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

        }

        else {

            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
        }*/


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return inviteeList.size();
    }
}
```

But the managedquery shows unresolved. How to do this? Please help. Thank you.

EDIT: I have an Invitee class and an Invitee activity in which I get the contacts list and its data and the I am selecting the contacts using check box and this list is stored in selected contacts and it is added in the server's database. I have an `AsyncTask` to `addInvitee` as well as `getInvitee`.

So In `InviteeActivity` I am calling `getInvitee` asyncTask from this I get the array of invited contacts. Now When I am showing this selected contacts list in `InviteeActivity` I want to show the image of a contact.

`AddInvitee` Activity:

```
public class AddInviteeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<Invitee> contact_list = null;
    private inviteeAdapter mInviteeAdapter;
    private String contactId,display_name,email,phone,image_uri;
    private ArrayList<Invitee> items;
    private ArrayList<Invitee> selectedContacts;
    boolean[] isChecked;
    Cursor mCursor;
    public ListView lv;
    public int RQS_PICK_CONTACT = 1,RQS_ADD_CONTACT = 2;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
    ArrayList<Integer> selectedItemsPositions;
    private ImageView done,back;
    private boolean mContactListActivity;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    public Invitee invitee;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_invitee);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("");
        TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

        toolbarTitle.setText("Select Contacts");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        done = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.done);

        back = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        contact_list = new ArrayList<Invitee>();

        selectedContacts = new ArrayList<Invitee>();

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        showContacts();

        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                invitee = new Invitee();

                Log.d("selectd",String.valueOf(selectedItemsPositions));

                mContactListActivity = true;

                selectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();//to store selected items


                for (Integer pos : selectedItemsPositions) {

                    selectedContacts.add(items.get(pos));
                }


                if(selectedContacts.size() == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(AddInviteeActivity.this,"Please Select Contact.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else {

                    Invitations invitations = new Invitations(1,selectedContacts);
                    new AddInviteeAsyncTask(AddInviteeActivity.this).execute(invitations);

                    finish();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void getContacts() {


        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };

        mCursor =  managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "upper("+ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");

        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

            invitee = new Invitee();

            Invitee photo = new Invitee();

            contactId = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            display_name = mCursor.getColumnName(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));


 invitee.setFName(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

            invitee.setEmail(getEmail(contactId));
            invitee.setMobile(getPhoneNumber(contactId));


            contact_list.add(invitee);
        }

        isChecked = new boolean[mCursor.getCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < isChecked.length; i++) {
            isChecked[i] = false;
        }

        this.mInviteeAdapter = new inviteeAdapter(AddInviteeActivity.this, R.layout.contact_list_item, contact_list);
        lv.setAdapter(this.mInviteeAdapter);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RQS_PICK_CONTACT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                getContacts();

            }
        }

    }

    public class inviteeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Invitee> {


        public inviteeAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Invitee> items1) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items1);
            items = items1;
            selectedItemsPositions = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        //to store all selected items position

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder mViewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, parent, false);
                mViewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                mViewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

                mViewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean ischecked) {
                        int position = (int) mViewHolder.cb.getTag();
                        if (ischecked) {
                            //check whether its already selected or not
                            if (!selectedItemsPositions.contains(position))
                                selectedItemsPositions.add(position);
                        } else {
                            //remove position if unchecked checked item
                            selectedItemsPositions.remove((Object) position);
                        }
                    }
                });

                convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
            } else {
                mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Invitee invitee = items.get(position);
            mViewHolder.cb.setTag(position);

            if (selectedItemsPositions.contains(position))
                mViewHolder.cb.setChecked(true);
            else
                mViewHolder.cb.setChecked(false);

            mViewHolder.name.setText(invitee.getFName());


            return convertView;
        }


        public class ViewHolder {
            CheckBox cb;
            TextView name;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted
                getContacts();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we can not display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private void showContacts()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
        }

        else {

            getContacts();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        //  mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        //this.recreate();
        if(mInviteeAdapter != null) {
            mInviteeAdapter.clear();
            getContacts();
        }
        // mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    private String getPhoneNumber(String contactId) {

        String phoneNumber = "";
        final String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, };
        final Cursor phone = managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);

        if (phone.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactNumberColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);

            while (!phone.isAfterLast()) {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber + phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex) + ";";
                phone.moveToNext();
            }

        }
        phone.close();
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    private String getEmail(String contactId) {
        String emailStr = "";
        final String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, // use
                // Email.ADDRESS
                // for API-Level
                // 11+
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE };

        final Cursor email = managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);

        if (email.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactEmailColumnIndex = email.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);

            while (!email.isAfterLast()) {
                emailStr = emailStr + email.getString(contactEmailColumnIndex) + ";";
                email.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        email.close();
        return emailStr;

    }

    public String getLastName()
    {

        String lastName = "";

        Cursor nameCur = AddInviteeActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);

        while (nameCur.moveToNext()) {
            String given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
            lastName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            String display = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));

        }
        nameCur.close();

        return lastName;
    }
    public String getPhoto(String contactId)
    {
        String imageUri ="";

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                imageUri = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
            }
        }

        return imageUri;
    }

}
```

InviteeActivity:

```
public class InviteeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GetInviteeAsyncTask.GetInvitees{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private InviteeAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Invitee> inviteeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private TextView alertText;
    private RelativeLayout content;
    private boolean mInvitee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invitee);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Invitee");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);

        new GetInviteeAsyncTask(this,InviteeActivity.this,inviteeList).execute(1L);

        alertText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alertText);
        content = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mInvitee = true;

                Intent i = new Intent(InviteeActivity.this,AddInviteeActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Invitee",mInvitee);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void doPostExecute(ArrayList<Invitee> response) {

        inviteeList = response;

        if(inviteeList.size() > 0)
        {
            alertText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            alertText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            content.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new InviteeAdapter(inviteeList,InviteeActivity.this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: do you want to load image from uri?

Comment: yes. from contacts @AsmaaRashad

Comment: the last question before posting my answer .. do you want load image in profileImage  after that commented line:
       // String imageUri = invitee.getImageUri();

Comment: yes, I want to show it in image view of profile image. And the photo should  match the selected contacts list so may be it will need to filter by the name of contacts.@AsmaaRashad

Comment: is that the url of the image or what it is :invitee.getImageUri();?

Answer (score 0):

to get Image From url it must be done in Asynchronous task so you should create Async Class as Following :

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        this.bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

    }


}
```

in your adapter change this line :

```
if(holder.imageUri!=null) {

            holder.profileImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(holder.imageUri));
        }
```

***TO:***

```
if(holder.imageUri!=null) {
 new DownloadImageTask(holder.profileImage ).execute(Uri.parse(holder.imageUri));
        }
```

Comment: try that and tell me if you still have problems

Comment: from where will i get YOUR_URL?@ Asmaa Rashad

Comment: `invitee.getImageUri();` isn't it the url that you want to load it's image ?

Comment: its commented , its of no use. I want to get the uri of image from contacts and set it to the image view. @Asmaa Rashad

Comment: i told you how to get image from url and how to get the url depends on your logic . in order to help you to get it please show me your contacts class and how to fill it and the relation between it and invitee element

Comment: is the class Invitee has a field String of photo url ? if yes you can do that directly: `new DownloadImageTask(profileImage ).execute(invitee.getImageUri());`

Comment: you start your adapter with selected contacts that came from getInvitee Async task so you can use the url of the invitee item in binding view directly . do you tried that?

Comment: In server there is not a parameter of image_uri. So I have not set it to the invitee object. I tried to create another object of invitee and set the uri ang get it in adapter. but i dint get the pic shown. @Asmaa Rashad

Comment: please see the  last update of my answer and tell me if it has a a problem or i misunderstand you ?